# Alterar um ou mais valor de parcelas, e automaticamente recalcular os outros campos

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

**Alterei da forma que eu queria, porem agora estou com problemas na formatação em real!**

[Link do exemplo](http://app.asolmg.com.br/app/tabela.php)

Segue o código alterado

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<center>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Parcela</th>
    <th>valor</th>
   
  </tr>
<?php
$total = "20000";
$total_parcelas = 5;
$i = 1;
while ($i <= $total_parcelas):     
$parcelas = $total / $total_parcelas;        
    
    ?>

 <tr>
    <td>Parcela <?php echo $i;?></td>
    <td> <input type="valor" id="<?php echo $i;?>" name="valor"  class="geral_parc val_parcela parcela_variavel" value="<?php echo $parcelas;?>"> </td>
</tr>



<?php    $i++;
endwhile;
?>

  </table>
    Total: <label class="show-total"></label>
</center>


<script>
    
        const round = (num, places) => {
            if (!("" + num).includes("e")) {
                    return +(Math.round(num + "e+" + places)  + "e-" + places);
            } else {
                    let arr = ("" + num).split("e");
                    let sig = ""
                    if (+arr[1] + places > 0) {
                            sig = "+";
                    }

                    return +(Math.round(+arr[0] + "e" + sig + (+arr[1] + places)) + "e-" + places);
            }
        } 
    
    
    $(function(){
        'use strict';
         
            
            $(".parcela_variavel").keyup(function(){
                var total_fix = 0;
                var total_var = 0;
                var total_geral = 0;
                var total_fixas = $('.parcela_fixa').length;
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var valor =  $('#'+id).val();
                $('#'+id).removeClass('val_parcela');
                $('#'+id).addClass('parcela_fixa');
                $('#'+id).removeClass('parcela_variavel');
              
               
                $(".parcela_variavel").each(function(index,element){
                   if ($(element).val()) {
                     total_fix+= parseInt($(element).val());    
                   }
               });
               
               $(".parcela_fixa").each(function(index,element){
                   if ($(element).val()) {
                     total_var+= parseInt($(element).val());    
                   }
               });
               
                $(".geral_parc").each(function(index,element){
                   if ($(element).val()) {
                     total_geral+= parseInt($(element).val());    
                   }
               });
               
               
              var restante =<?php echo $total;?> - total_var; 
               
               
               var n_parcelas_flutuantes = <?php echo $total_parcelas;?> - total_fixas;
               
               var parcelas_flutuantes = restante / n_parcelas_flutuantes
                $(".val_parcela").val(parcelas_flutuantes);
               
             
               $(".show-total").text(total_fix + ' - ' + total_var +  ' - '+ total_geral + ' - ' + restante);
            });
              
              
              
        
        
        
     });
        
</script>
```

Estou criando um sistema que e necessário dividir um determinado valor em x parcelas, ate ai tudo bem, o problema e que o cliente pode mudar o valor de uma ou mais parcelas, e com isso o sistema precisa calcular as parcelas restantes e dividir pelas parcelas que não foram alteradas

A divisão e alteração de uma parcela eu consegui criar de forma bem  rustica.

o que ta me matando e a questão de poder alterar este valor em mais parcelas, pensei em colocar um Checkbox para marcar como fixa, mas não estou conseguindo pensar em como fazer este processo.

Comment: Essa alteração na parcela, vai alterar o saldo devedor do cliente? Isso me parece mais um problema na matemática e lógica de montar o que precisa. Diga que você tem R$ 2000/5  = 5 parcelas de R$400,00. Se eu altera uma parcela de 400 para 200, tenho a diferença de 200 para distribuir nas outras parcelas, isso se o saldo devedor não muda.

Comment: Sim, ira alterar o saldo devedor, mas no final eu tenho que realizar a comparação de todas a parcelas e comparar no valor devido, e assim o usuário ira adequar o valor eu alguma parcela para que se ajuste ao saldo devedor real.